# Mellin transform of $f(1-x)$

Tags: integration, complex-integration, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The Mellin transform of f(x) is defined as follows:
$$M[f(x);s]=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(x) dx\ = F(s)$$ 
This integral transform obeys several nice (and easy to prove) properties, such as:
$$M[x^n f(x);s] = F(s+n)$$
$$M[f(x^p);s] = \frac{1}{p}F(s/p) $$ 
Does there exist a similar property for the Mellin transform of $f(1-x)$
$$ M[f(1-x);s] = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(1-x) dx\ $$
in terms of $F(s)$?

Comment: I doubt so. Is there a specific problem behind?

Comment: Yeah, wanted to see how $F(s)$ changes under $ x\to 1-x $ and $x \to 1/x$. This had some application elsewhere, in physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For one thing, most of the values of $f(x)$ in the integral for $F(s)$ are completely different from the values of $f(1-x)$ in $M(f(1-x))$: the former takes values from $f([0,\infty))$, while the latter uses $f((-\infty,1])$.

Comment: True, this happens for $M[f(1-x)]$, unlike the cases of $M[x^n f(x)]$ or $M[f(x^p)]$. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, the Mellin transform is a multiplicative-coordinate analogue of Fourier transform, and like the symmetry of Fourier under $f(x)\to f(-x)$, there is a symmetry of Mellin under $f(x)\to f(1/x)$. But/and we can extend "Mellin transform" to the group $\mathbb R\asymp (0,+\infty)\times {\pm 1}$,  but this doesn't change much, since functions on $\mathbb-\{0\}$ are just pairs of functions on $(0,\infty)$.